# Regulation term disappears during taking gradient of cost function by using backpropagation

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

I'm trying to take the derivative of the cost function with respect to parameter $\theta$. The problem is $\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta}$, somehow, is not equal to $\frac{dJ(\theta)}{dz}\cdot \frac{dz}{d\theta}$.

The posterior probability or softmax of $ z_j^{(i)} = \theta_jx^{(i)}$ is 
$p_j^{(i)} = \frac{\exp(\theta_jx^{(i)})}{\sum_k \exp(\theta_k x^{(i)})}$ where $x^{(i)}$ is $i^\text{th}$ sample and $\theta_j$ is the parameters coming in to $j^\text{th}$ neuron.

Before passing into cost derivative, softmax derivative is evaluated.

$$
\newcommand{\for}{\text{for }}
\frac{dp_j^{(i)}}{dz_k} = \begin{cases} p_j^{(i)} (1-p_k^{(i)}) &\for j = k  \\
(-p_j^{(i)}p_k^{(i)}) &\for j \neq k  \end{cases}  \tag{1}
$$

(I found this more helpful than single equation by using Kronecker's delta)

Similarly,

$$
\frac{dp_j^{(i)}}{d\theta_k} = \begin{cases} x^{(i)} p_j^{(i)} (1-p_k^{(i)}) &\for  j = k \\ 
x^{(i)}(-p_j^{(i)}p_k^{(i)}) &\for j \neq k \end{cases}  \tag{2}
$$

The cost function is:

$$
J(\theta) = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i \sum_j y_j^{(i)} \ln(p_j^{(i)}) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}^2  \tag{3}
$$

where $y_j^{(i)}$ is the label matrix.

$$
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i \sum_j y_j^{(i)} \frac{1}{p_j^{(i)}} \frac{dp_j^{(i)}}{d\theta_k} + \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}  \tag{4}
$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(4)$:

\begin{align}
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x^{(i)}\bigg(&\sum_{j=k} y_j^{(i)} \frac{1}{p_j^{(i)}} p_j^{(i)} (1-p_k^{(i)}) +   \\
&\sum_{j \neq k} y_j^{(i)} \frac{1}{p_j^{(i)}} (-p_j^{(i)}p_k^{(i)})\bigg) + \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}  \tag{5}
\end{align}

$p_j^{(i)}$ is substituted in $(5)$,

$$
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x^{(i)}\bigg( y_k^{(i)} (1-p_k^{(i)}) - \sum_{j \neq k} y_j^{(i)} p_k^{(i)}\bigg) + \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}  \tag{6}
$$

By taking $p_k^{(i)}$ parenthesis,

$$
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x^{(i)}\bigg(y_k^{(i)}- p_k^{(i)} \sum_j  y_j^{(i)}\bigg) + \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}  \tag{7}
$$

$p_k^{(i)} \sum_j  y_j^{(i)} = 1$, since it has only one non-zero entry which equal to $1$.

$$
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x^{(i)}(y_k^{(i)}- p_k^{(i)}) + \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}  \tag{8}
$$

Now, I derive $\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k}$ by using $\frac{dJ(\theta)}{dz_k}\cdot \frac{dz_k}{d\theta_k}$. The procedure is very similar, so most of the steps are skipped.

\begin{align}
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{dz_k} &= -\frac{1}{m} \sum_i (y_k^{(i)}- p_k^{(i)}) \tag{9}  \\[5pt]
\frac{dz_k}{d\theta_k}  &= x^{(i)} \tag{10}  \\[5pt]
\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta_k} &= \frac{dJ(\theta)}{dz_k}\cdot \frac{dz_k}{d\theta_k} = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x^{(i)}(y_k^{(i)}- p_k^{(i)})  \tag{11}
\end{align}

As you can see, $(8)$ and $(11)$ are the same except the regulation (weight decay) term. I couldn't find the mistake that I made. In $(9)$ derivative with respect to $z_k$ should eliminate the regulation term, shouldn't it?

Edit: derivation of regulation term:

\begin{align}
R(\theta) &= \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}^2   \\
          &= \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \begin{bmatrix}
  \theta_{1j}^2 \\
  \theta_{2j}^2 \\
  \vdots       \\
  \theta_{kj}^2 
 \end{bmatrix}  \\[20pt]
\frac{\partial R(\theta)}{\partial \theta_k} &= \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_j \sum_k \begin{bmatrix}
  2\theta_{1j} \\
  2\theta_{2j} \\
  \vdots       \\
  2\theta_{kj} 
 \end{bmatrix}   \\
 &= \lambda \sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}
\end{align}

Comment: Your function $J$ get parameter ${\theta}$, so where this value in function (I think in left side you write in matrix form and in right in scalar)? Also why you try differentiate $J(\theta)$ by $\theta_k$, this look like you differentiate by some row or column (if $\theta$ is a weight matrix and $\theta_{kj}$ is synapse)? So this problems make some confuse and maybe you need retest your computation.

Comment: @itdxer full notation of $\theta$ is $\theta_{kj}$ where k is the number of outputs and j is number of inputs for softmax layer.So $\theta_{kj}$ is parameter matrix of softmax layer.

Comment: $\sum_j \sum_k \theta_{kj}^2$ - Does that mean that you try make quadratic of every element and sum all of them from matrix $\theta$?

Comment: @itdxer yes, that is L2-regularization. Like in [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Backpropagation_Algorithm)

Comment: So how you try differentiate this sum of all matrix elements by $\theta_k$ and in differentiation output get all this values again in differentiate form? Does all values $\theta_{kj}$ contains $\theta_k$?

Comment: @itdxer I've added derivation of regulation term at the end. please check it.

Comment: I used some additional $\LaTeX$ in an attempt to make your Q a little more readable. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.